# mysql unique column for mobile number

Tags: mysql

I have a table users, with the following table structure

```
id
name
email_id (primary and unique)
mobile_number
active
```

with the row values:

```
1 Chris chris@gmail.com 9042699090 1
2 Roger roger@gmail.com null       0
3 mark  mark@gmail.com  null       0
```

now i need to change the column mobile_number to be unique, when i set the unique key via phpmyadmin, i got the error Duplicate entry `9042699090`, how can i resolve this error.

Comment: if chris and roger have the same mobile number, moblie number can't be unique

Comment: you can not make mobile number UNIQUE column because there duplicate records for mobile number you mentioned.
you have to delete one entry or make other column unique.

Comment: ok, can null be updated in the mobile_number

Comment: NULL values can be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query shows you the duplicate values. You have to remove all duplicates before you can create a unique key.

```
SELECT mobile_number
FROM users
GROUP BY mobile_number
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: No. You can have many NULL values, but must have unique NOT-NULLs.